# trying to scanf value in a function to a struct inside a struct with a pointer

Tags: pointers, struct

just look at the code please , says it all

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>

struct DOB
{
int y,m,d;
}typedef DOB_t;

struct Courses
{
char* NameofCourse;
char* Lec;
int CourseID;

}typedef Course_t;

struct Student
{
char Name[20];
float Grade;
DOB_t dob;
Course_t Courses;

}typedef Student_t;

void addstudent(Student_t* s);
void addDate(DOB_t* dob);
void addCourse(Course_t* c);

main()
{
int opt;
Student_t s;
printf("Please choose one of the options:\n");
printf("<<<<<1.add student>>>>>\n<<<<<2.print student>>>>>\n");
scanf("%d",&opt);
switch(opt)
    case 1:
{
    addstudent(&s);
    break;
}

}

void addstudent(Student_t* s)
{
printf("Enter student's name: ");
scanf("%s",s->Name);
printf("Enter Grade: ");
scanf("%.2f",s->Grade);
printf("Enter DateOfBirth: ");
***addDate(&(s->dob));***
addCourse(&(s->Courses));
}

void addDate(DOB_t* dob)
{
***scanf("%d %d %d", dob->d,dob->m,dob->y);***
}

void addCourse(Course_t* c)
{
printf("Enter Course Name And Lec Name: ");
scanf("%s %s",c->NameofCourse,c->Lec);
printf("Enter Course ID: ");
scanf("%d",c->CourseID);
}
```

it's not finished yet , but look at the highlighted row - i get an error when i'm triyng to scan values of DateofBirth using pointers into (s->DOB ) to keep the data in the value after function closes. 
hope you understand my problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`scanf` requires you to pass the address of the memory space you want to store the result in. In your functions, wherever you are passing pointer to the structure,you should use `scanf` like this.

```
void addDate(DOB_t* dob)
{
scanf("%d %d %d", &dob->d,&dob->m,&dob->y); //This would read an integer into the address of pointer plus the offset of member into the structure.
}
```

You have make this change in your code at every place where you are reading values into structure pointer.

Comment: thank you ! it really helps and everything when fine till i got many errors out of nowhere :